# Using PLCrashReporter on Mac OS

Tags: macos, cocoa, plcrashreporter

1. Is there any sample code available for using PLCrashReporter in a Mac app?
2. Does PLCrashReporter work in a command line Objective-C program as well?
3. Does PLCrashReporter handle all signals like SIGTERM?

There are enough samples available for iOS but not for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used PLCrashReporter, but a few seconds exploring the [PLCrashReporter web site](https://www.plcrashreporter.org) turned up [a thread in which someone received a reply from an author about a problem using it with a Mac](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/plcrashreporter/mac/plcrashreporter/KQX5WaIztKg/XjJOa6oGokYJ). While it looks as though it was designed with iOS in mind, "official" opinion seems to indicate it's not iOS specific and should work just fine on Mac OS.

In any case, I think you'd have more luck joining [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/plcrashreporter/mac/plcrashreporter/Y_49-71MuF4/P-YlQVaE0wsJ), which was started just over a week ago as of the time of this post. Maybe if you add your own voice, the author(s) will provide a specific example.

In all likelihood, though, [the example provided by their documentation](https://www.plcrashreporter.org/documentation/api/v1.2/example_usage_iphone.html) should work almost exactly the same with the Mac `UIApplication` analog, `NSApplication`, with a little adaptation. I make this assumption because the author seems to think it'll work just fine on the Mac and that it's obvious how to make it work. I'd make this assumption if I were scouting PLCrashReporter for my own use so I did what I always do in that situation. I looked at the documentation and a bit at the code. A quick look convinced me that just substituting the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol method `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application` with the Mac `NSApplicationDelegate` equivalent `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification` should make it work in a Mac app.

The `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method is probably already stubbed out in the default application delegate class the Mac app template Xcode provides to every new project. Just copy and paste the example method's body into the stub if it's already there. Make sure you follow the author's build phase advice in the first thread so relevant libraries and resources go along for the ride when you build your app.

I haven't tried this, but if did, I'd copy the `-handleCrashReport` method verbatim into my app delegate, and copy the *body* of the `...DidFinishLaunching:` hook into the template's body (you may already have some code there; slap it in before or after yours, whichever makes sense if it makes any difference at all). I'd import the necessary headers into the app delegate since it probably won't find `PLCrashReporter` or any of its related symbols otherwise. I'd also make sure the Framework/library/resources is properly linked and that it's copied into the app bundle, and then I'd hit Run and see what happens, solving problems as I go.

Try it. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: hi, Thanks for your reply. I tried leveraging the iOS Code on MAC, however without success. It appears that MAC behaves rather differently as when I emulate a crash using NSAssert or accessing an array at an undefined index, the exception trace is logged to console as other logs and the app doesn't even crash and consequently quit. If I send a SIGTERM, and relaunch the app crash reporter doesn't go inside loadPendingCrashReportDataAndReturnError which hints that its not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think PLCrashReporter doesn't do anything when running in the debugger - to allow you to debug reasonably, and catch symbolic exceptions in the debugger. Try to see if it works in "Release" builds that you run autonomously (maybe even debug builds, that you run directly from Finder/Command-line, not from the debugger).

Comment: Thanks @Joshua for your educated guesswork. Seems reasonable. I'm on the edge of diving in myself - but what would you guess better? link against the Mac framework or against the static lib of PLCrashReporter?

Comment: @MottiShneor I'm really not sure if there's any benefit to one over the other on a Mac app. I suppose it's mostly up to developer preference. I'd go with the Mac framework personally (because I've been an OS X developer since 10.0) just out of habit and having not heard anything specific whether one or the other approach is better).

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi I must say "diving in" only brought more questions and less answers. PLCrashReporter is designed for mainstream iOS and Mac Apps (meaning ObjC, NSApplication and Foundation based). Alas, I have a "unix style" C++ daemon (don't blame me - it's my employer and the genre - security tools) I don't find the slightest clue how to integrate a Crash-reporting thing (PLCrashReporter, Google break pad, etc) and just don't find my way out. Wish I was developing real Mac things again...

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure any of those platform-specific solutions would work for you, then.